# How to change the font size in terminal from terminal without the use of a mouse

Tags: command-line, fonts

I am working with LXTerminal 0.2.0 and want to know how to change the font size to make it easier in my eyes and for general knowledge so that I can do it in the absence of a mouse since that is what normally exists.  I am trying to learn to be self sufficient working by myself with no mouse in a normal terminal environment.  I am working with ubuntu 16.04lts.  Please don't refer to gui as I know how that works.

Comment: alt-E pulls up the EDIT menu, <up> arrow then <enter> selects preferences, then I could tab to 'terminal font' & alter font size with <arrow>, <tab> & <enter> keys.   *I do realize you want a quick key way - but it works (I don't use lxterminal so haven't looked for better)*

Comment: When you press (and hold) the `alt` key, the hotkeys for the pulldown menu items are underlined. Use `E` (while still holding the `alt` key) in English, and some other letter in other languages, for example `R` in Swedish, which stands for 'Redigera'.

Comment: What does `Ctrl` plus `Shift` plus the `equals` key do when all three keys are pressed together? In LXTerminal 0.3, that increases the font size (and window size) and `Ctrl` plus `shift` plus the `minus` sign decreases the font size (and the window size).

Comment: For me in Lubuntu 18.04 LTS with `lxterminal 0.3.1` I can also use **`ctrl` and `+`** to increase the font and **`ctrl` and `shift` and `-`** to decrease the font. But this is only temporary. Do it via the Edit menu, if you want to change the settings in a persistent way.

Answer (score 3):

The configuration file for lxterminal is: `$HOME/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf` with the default font and size showing as:

```
fontname=Monospace 12
```

Simply alter this with your favourite command line editor such as vim and your changes are made. However it would be far *cooler* to use sed to accomplish with something like the following one-liner:

```
sed -i_bak '/^fontname/s/[0-9][0-9]$/22/' $HOME/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
```

This works by:

1. `sed -i_bak`: Make the changes inline and save a backup of the original file with the suffix `_bak`
2. `'/^fontname/`: Match the line with 'fontname' at the beginning.
3. `s/[0-9][0-9]$/22/'` Substitute the last 2 numbers with '22' or the number for the size of the font that you require.

How cool is the command line!

**References:**

- [How to use sed to modify last 2 digit of a line when a string matches in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322676/how-to-use-sed-to-modify-last-2-digit-of-a-line-when-a-string-matches-in-a-file)